# request.body providing all information for nodemailer but email

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm creating a simple contact form for my node.js and express web app and I'm using nodemailer to do so.

As of now, everything works as it should - the information is recorded on the server and is emailed to the desired inbox. However! All the information (fname, lname, phone, company and comment) is included in the message but the email section is returned as --- email: ''. Not an error or anything just blank.

Also to be clear -- the email: '' -- comes up in the server - but on the email sent via the function, there is no email title or space for it to be provided.

I've tried reformatting the html body section and have tried to debug any issues with the form or the javascript, but have come up empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks !

The app.js is laid out as follows:

```
//jshint eversion:6

const http = require('http')
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const ejs = require('ejs');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const path = require('path');
const port = 3000;


const app = express();


app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());



// custom middleware to log data access
const log = function (request, response, next) {
    console.log(`${new Date()}: ${request.protocol}://${request.get('host')}${request.originalUrl}`);
    console.log(request.body); // make sure JSON middleware is loaded first
    next();
}
app.use(log);
// end custom middleware


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('images'));



app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/prices", function (req, res, ) {
    res.render("prices");
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res, ) {
    res.render("about");
});
app.get("/contact", function (req, res, ) {
    res.render("contact");
});

module.exports = function () {
    this.Categories = require('tools.js');
}



// HTTP POST
app.post("/ajax/email", function (request, response) {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com", // this should be YOUR GMAIL account
            pass: "XXXXXX" // this should be your password
        }
    });

    var textBody = `FROM: ${request.body.fname}  EMAIL: ${request.body.email} MESSAGE: ${request.body.comment}`;
    var htmlBody = `<h2>Mail From Contact Form</h2> <p>from: ${request.body.fname} ${request.body.lname} </p> <p>${request.body.email}</p>  <p>${request.body.phone}</p> <p>${request.body.company}</p><p>${request.body.comment}</p>`;
    var mail = {
        from: "DeltaDesignsGlobal@gmail.com", // sender address
        to: "james.a.vandenberg@gmail.com", // list of receivers (THIS COULD BE A DIFFERENT ADDRESS or ADDRESSES SEPARATED BY COMMAS)
        subject: "Mail From Contact Form", // Subject line
        text: textBody,
        html: htmlBody
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mail, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.json({
                message: "message not sent: an error occured; check the server's console log"
            });
        } else {
            response.json({
                message: `Thanks for reaching out! We'll contact you ASAP`
            });
        }
    });
});


const PORT = process.env || port;


// const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
//     res.statusCode = 200;
//     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
//     res.end('Hello World! NodeJS \n');
// });

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

The form and Java is:

```
 <div class="contact-form" id="contact-id">
          <form action="/ajax/email" class="contact-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitEmailForm(this);">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lname">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="company">Company:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Enter Company Name" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Question:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment">What services are you interested in?</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- <hr>
<div class="contactQuote">
  <h1>Coming together is a beginning, <br>
    staying together is progress, <br>
    & working together is success.
  </h1>
</div>
<hr> -->
<!-- <div col-12 class="contactCollabImg">
  <img class="contactImg2" src="images/contactcollabImg.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
</div> -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitEmailForm(form) {
    var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    obj.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(obj.readyState == 4){
        if(obj.status == 200){
          var res = JSON.parse(obj.responseText);
          alert(res.message); 
        }
        else{
          alert("XMLHttp status " + obj.status + ":Failed to Send Message " + obj.statusText);
        }
      }
    };
    obj.open("post", form.action, true);
    obj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // NOTICE: "application/json"
    obj.send(JSON.stringify({ fname: form.fname.value, lname: form.lname.value, email: form.email.value, phone: form.phone.value, company: form.company.value, comment: form.comment.value }));
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had forgot to change the 'name' field on some of the form elements from email to their respective id after copying and pasting during writing.

That cleared it up!